# How to correct div overlapping the title

Tags: css, positioning

**EDIT**: Added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gdHuh/

On my page there is a title with a bottom border. There is padding between the title and the border. Floating to the right on the title area, touching the bottom border, is a search box. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

However, when the title and search box text are too long, then part of the title text is hidden by the search box:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like in cases like this:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column column8">
        <h1>Internship Reviews &amp; Rankings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="findTop column column8">
        <div class="greyShaded findTab">
            <img class="verticalBottom" src="images/blueMagnify.png"/> 
            <a>Find an Internship Program</a> 
            <img class="verticalTextTop" src="images/greyArrowheadRight.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
/* More Specific CSS */    
.findTab{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.findTop{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: -23px;
}

/* More general CSS */
.row {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.column {
    margin: 0 15px;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.column8 {
    width: 610px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

How can I change the HTML and CSS so that the elements will be laid out correctly?

Comment: put this working example in a fiddle

Comment: to get that behavior dynamically, instead of using pre-defined width values, you will need to use javascript. With CSS you can only work with pre-defined width-values and that gives a problem when you change the link text.

Comment: Try with word-wrap [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/gdHuh/3/) for my result

To avoid adding another class I used

```
.row div:nth-of-type(1){
  width:300px;
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

I also removed the `.column8` and replaced it with `.row div`, because in this code format, that is what is most appropriate

**Edit**

Another alternative would be to keep all the code the same, but add

```
h1 {
  width:300px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/gdHuh/4/)

This option seems to be closer to what you are looking for

Comment: I see, based on the tab's contents being about 300px. So when it just says Find a School use a different width.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in this case the best method which can helps you is using jQuery. I modified a bit your code and now it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanz/gdHuh/2/). You can resize the "Result" area to be sure that everything is ok. Also you can play with `white-space` css property ( add it on class 'title' ).

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be to set a width percentage for the title (to allow for different screen sizes) and then do `white-space: pre` to make the text wrap. For more specific advice, you'll need to put up a fiddle.